# Mule: Is Mule ESB 3.5.1 is a stable version or Beta version?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

Could you please anyone suggest Mule ESB 3.5.1 (July 2014) release is a Beta release or Stable version which we can suggest client to use.

I have gone through few websites, but i didn't find anything kind of Beta version or stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is GA and considered stable. Early access editions are normally appended via milestone number: M1, M2 etc. Here is the guide on Mule's release strategy: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Release+Strategy

This guide details ones marked * are "For evaluation purposes only. Early Access versions are not recognized by MuleSoft support when used by customers in development or production environments."